# How to make emacs works like "ipython manage.py shell" with django?

Tags: python, django, emacs

I am new to emacs and Django.

I've found ipython quite convenient, especially its TAB completion.
In a ipython Django shell, TAB completion is quit convenient because it also includes Django setting. But when I open a python file, with "emacs -nw models.py" for example, the TAB completion for Django related module no longer works that well.

Can any body help? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

If auto-completion is what you need, then use [rope](http://rope.sourceforge.net/index.html).

Although default auto-complite hotkey is different (`M-/`), it works pretty clever and provides list of other useful features.

Comment: Thank you! Rope is really helpful! But I still have no idea how to include the Django settings like that in "ipython manage.py shell".

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to try this:
Emacs as a Django IDE with python-django.el

http://from-the-cloud.com/en/emacs/2013/01/28_emacs-as-a-django-ide-with-python-djangoel.html

with auto-complete and jedi setup you can do the TAB completion just like Ipython with django models and views.

also it has a wonderfun binding for ipdb to trace a bug called pdbtracking.

You will love it. Thanks